# PHP Decoding Array Within Json Object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am stuck with this Json data:

I have this info in a variable:

```
$mydata= '{"success":true,"data":[{"sku":203823,"issoldout":false,"isShowDiscount":false,"discount":0,"currencycode":"USD","currencysymbol":"US$","price":"10.20","listprice":"","adddate":"4/23/2013"}]}';
```

I have managed to tell if success is true or not by doing this:

```
$obj = JSON_decode($mydata, true);

if ($obj['success'] != 1) {
    print 'Does Not Exist<br />';
}
else{
    print $obj['success']."<br/>";
}
```

where `echo $obj['success'];` is equal to 1 if True and 0 if False.

What is getting me stuck is how to get at the keys in the "data":[] array.

I tried `print $obj['data'][0];` and  `print $obj['data']['sku'];` but both returned nothing.

Any ideas on how to get the info out would be welcomed.

Comment: Use single quotes around the mydata string.

Comment: Also missing semi colon on the end of your string.   JSON_decode is actuall json_decode.

Comment: fixed. Just a copy-paste mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$data` is an array so:

`echo $obj['data'];` should print "Array"

`echo $obj['data'][0]['sku'];` should print "203823"

Answer (score 1):

```
 $mydata= "{"success":true,"data":[{...}]}"
```

`$mydata['data']` contains an array of objects.

In `json` the `{..}` contents are for objects, and `[..]` are for arrays.

So you would go

```
foreach($obj['data'] as $items)
{
    echo $items['sku'];
}
```

I'm using `foreach` because there could be more than one object in your JSON result.

Answer (score 0):

See my comments, this code runs successfully.

```
$mydata= '{"success":true,"data":[{"sku":203823,"issoldout":false,"isShowDiscount":false,"discount":0,"currencycode":"USD","currencysymbol":"US$","price":"10.20","listprice":"","adddate":"4/23/2013"}]}';

$obj = json_decode($mydata, TRUE);

if ($obj['success'] != 1) {
  print 'Does Not Exist<br />';
}
else{
  print $obj['success']."<br/>";
}
```